# tmux configuration conditional to OS

Tags: tmux

There's some lines of my `tmux.conf` which I'd like executed only if my OS is Mac. However, I'd like to use my `tmux.conf` on multiple different operating systems. How can I make a command conditional to the OS on which tmux is currently running?

Comment: version detect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016458/how-to-write-if-statement-in-tmux-conf-to-set-different-options-for-different-t

Answer (score 65):

Use the `if-shell` command:

```
if-shell "uname | grep -q Darwin" "tmux-cmd1; tmux-cmd2;" "tmux-cmd3; tmux-cmd4"
```

You may want to put OS-specific commands in separate files, and execute them via the "source-file" command.

```
if-shell "uname | grep -q Darwin" "source-file .tmux-macosx" "source-file .tmux-linux"
```

Comment: The `if-shell` and `run-shell` *tmux* commands are currently asynchronous (as of *tmux* 1.7); they effectively run their shell command in the background, and any *tmux* commands that they run will only be executed **after** any commands that come after the `if-shell` or `run-shell` command itself (*tmux* is single-threaded). Effectively, if you use `if-shell` or `run-shell` in `~/.tmux.conf`, the initial session (and any sessions, windows, or panes created explicitly created through `~/tmux.conf`) will lack any *tmux* configuration arranged through `if-shell` or `run-shell` commands.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen `if-shell` works as expected for me with tmux 1.8. I am using it to set set-titles-string only for SSH: https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/commit/cd9e2b0115f579af0954ea89d9b542d4230df2e3

Comment: This should be accepted; it's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

Jimeh https://github.com/jimeh/dotfiles/commit/3838db8 has the answer. Also Chris Johnsen deserves a lot of credit for helping people on the GitHub issue here: https://Github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/8#issuecomment-4134987

Basically, you set up a shell script called `safe-reattach-to-user-namespace` that checks for the existence of the real reattach... command.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# If reattach-to-user-namespace is not available, just run the command.
if [ -n "$(command -v reattach-to-user-namespace)" ]; then
  reattach-to-user-namespace $@
else
  exec "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The if-shell check must be in a string and the command to run must be enclosed in `{}`. Here is an example of how to bind the `]` key to paste the system clipboard, with a command that varies depending on the operating system.

```
if-shell 'uname | grep -q Linux' { bind-key ] run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer" } 
if-shell 'uname | grep -q Darwin' { bind ] run "reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer" }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).